# Why isn't this regex working? It should be working based on diveintopython3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

```
pattern='''

^                     #beginning of string

M{0,3}              # thousands- 0 to 3 MS

(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})    # hundreds - 900 (CM), 400 (CD), 0-300 (0 to 3 Cs), or 500-800 (D, followed by 0 to 3 Cs)

(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})    # tens - 90 (XC), 40 (XL), 0-30 (0 to 3 Xs), or 50-80 (L, followed by 0 to 3 Xs)

(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})    # ones - 9 (IX), 4 (IV), 0-3 (0 to 3 Is), or 5-8 (V, followed by 0 to 3 Is)

$                   #end of string
'''
```

According to the diveintopython3 website and from my logic, re.search(pattern,'M',re.VERBOSE) should return that the string was matched, but I have no return when I enter call re.search. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me:

```
romanstring = "M"
m = re.search(pattern, romanstring, re.VERBOSE)
print(m.string)
```

Perhaps you were confused because re.search returns a "match object" instead of returning the matched string directly.

Comment: When I called re.search, nothing was returned though. Not even a match object

Comment: It returns None if the input string does not match the regex. However, when I copy-pasted the code you provided it worked just fine, both in Python3 and Python2.

Comment: @HSCoder: I would recommend writing a standalone ".py" that showcases your problem and edit your question to include that verbatim. You would just have to add 2 or 3 lines to your current code and it would allow anyone to test *exactly* what you are running. Maybe its just some silly typo somewhere.